# No Camera in Skype

Tags: macos, camera, skype

I have Retina MBP with 10.9.1 installed Mac OS X.

I have Skype 6.12. 
I'm not using video camera everyday ;) but I'm using Skype every day, and someday when I need it in Skype I saw that it was not detected, so I can't use it. From that point I've started to monitor that situation. And I've found that every time after while the camera is gone...

At the moment the solution is an OS X restart, but I don't like that solution.

Is there any other solution, or any possibility to get know why the system is losing access to the camera.

By the way, when the camera is lost, it is also not available in any other software like: Viber, Photo Booth, Facetime etc...

Comment: People used to have that problem with the Mavericks and Skype, but it was addressed with new updates. You might have a different problem, where some app on your system is taking over the video.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This command from shell:

```
sudo killall VDCAssistant
```

restores the camera for me every time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it is not Skype doing it, since all other video programs do not see your build in camera as well.

You might be a good candidate for [this fix from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2090).

Resetting computer to fix it, indicates you do have the problem described in the article.